# VB.Net Check if URL have valid image

Tags: vb.net

I need a hand, I'll explain.
I wish I could check if the inserted url contains a valid image, can you give me an example?

```vb
Public Function CheckAddress() As Boolean
        Try
            Dim URL As String = (URL HERE)
            Dim request As WebRequest = WebRequest.Create(URL)
            Dim response As WebResponse = request.GetResponse()
        Catch ex As Exception
            Return False
        End Try
        Return True
    End Function
```

This code tell if the url is valid or not, but i want it for checking the image

Answer (score 2):

Take a look at the `ContentType` property of the WebResponse object. If it contains one of (partial list):

- image/bmp
- image/gif
- image/vnd.microsoft.icon
- image/jpeg
- image/png
- image/svg+xml
- image/tiff

For a full list of Content (or Mime) types see: [Media Types @ IANA.org](https://www.iana.org/assignments/media-types/media-types.xhtml)

Add the code below after you get the response from the request.

```
If (response.ContentType.ToUpper.StartsWith("IMAGE")) Then
    Return True
Else
    Return False
End If
```

Or a more succinct way of writing this,

```
Return (response.ContentType.ToUpper.StartsWith("IMAGE"))
```

If you want to do further checks to see if the remote site is masking a file with different headers, you will need to download the remote file and then analyse it locally using other means.